# Using this with setTimeOut function stopped working

Tags: jquery, settimeout, each

I've created a function to loop through the divs in a parent div called 'rolloverimages' using an `.each` function. I want there to be a delay between when each image which is being generated so I am using `setTimeOut`. My problem is as soon as I added the setTimeOut function, the variables in using `this` aren't relating to the main `rollovers` variable.

Can anyone help please?

```
function rolloverImages() {

    $('.thumbnail-wrapper').one('mouseover', function() {
        var rollovers = $(this).find('.rolloverimages div');
        var time = 0;

        rollovers.each(function() {
            setTimeout(function() {
                var datasrc = $(this).data('hover');
                var img = $('<img id="dynamic">');
                var imgsrc = img.attr('src', datasrc);
                var parent = $(this).parent('.rolloverimages').parent('.thumbnail-wrapper');
                console.log(parent);
            }, time);
            time += 2000;
        });
    }); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have either to add var that=this before the setTimeout call (and use that instead of this) or bind the function to this :

```
function rolloverImages() {

          $('.thumbnail-wrapper').one('mouseover', function() {
            var rollovers = $(this).find('.rolloverimages div');
            var time = 0;

            rollovers.each(function() {
               setTimeout(function() {
                  var datasrc = $(this).data('hover');
                  var img = $('<img id="dynamic">');
                  var imgsrc = img.attr('src', datasrc);
                  var parent = $(this).parent('.rolloverimages').parent('.thumbnail-wrapper');
                  console.log(parent);
                }.bind(this), time);
                time += 2000;
            });

        });

    }
```